# iPhone - Twitter "Select and copy the PIN" issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to enable "login with Twitter" option in my app.
For this I'm using `Twitter-OAuth-iPhone` library (do I really need all this library just to login?)

Anyway after user enter his twitter username & password and Authorize the app, I'm getting to a view with "Select and copy the PIN" message, and I'm stuck without anything to do..

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: have u found the answer?? i am also stucked on the same,.,.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/issues/79

Comment: yes., i have used that code.,.,it is crashed,if i am giving Wrong password and try to post.,.have u tried to give wrong passWord for Twitter.,.,

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
- (NSString *)locatePin {
    NSString *pin = [[_theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:newPinJS]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    if (pin.length == 7) {
        return pin;
    } else {
        pin = [[_theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:oldPinJS]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        if (pin.length == 7) {
            return pin;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

add these after the `@implementation` of your class:

```
static NSString * const newPinJS = @"var d = document.getElementById('oauth-pin'); if (d == null) d = document.getElementById('oauth_pin'); if (d) { var d2 = d.getElementsByTagName('code'); if (d2.length > 0) d2[0].innerHTML; }";
static NSString * const oldPinJS = @"var d = document.getElementById('oauth-pin'); if (d == null) d = document.getElementById('oauth_pin'); if (d) d = d.innerHTML; d;";
```

and you need a library to login, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207317/ios-how-to-fetch-tweet-from-twitter-api-1-1/17207745#17207745) provide an answer how to login if you need it.