# iOS : How to fetch tweet from Twitter API 1.1

Tags: ios

Twitter has deprecated its API 1.0 and implemented new API 1.1
As per the new API we need to authentication before fetching the public time line.

I read the new API documentation here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1
but I have not clear idea, how to implement it in iOS.

Can anyone tell me the best way to fetch public time-line form Twitter using the API 1.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now I am using Public library specified on the twitter dev forum https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries                             But is there any other way like creating  app token by logi in twitter dev forum and that to fetch teets instead of LogOn in twitter

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to `Authenticate` your request (Get permission).

second, see follow these steps:

1.Download `FHSTwitterEngine` Twitter Library.

2.Add the folder `FHSTwitterEngine`" to your project and `#import "FHSTwitterEngine.h".`

3.add `SystemConfiguration.framework` to your project.

> Usage : 1.in the `[ViewDidLoad]` add the following code.

```
UIButton *logIn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    logIn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
    [logIn setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logIn addTarget:self action:@selector(showLoginWindow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:logIn];

[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]permanentlySetConsumerKey:@"<consumer_key>" andSecret:@"<consumer_secret>"];
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]setDelegate:self];
and don't forget to import the delegate FHSTwitterEngineAccessTokenDelegate.

you need to get the permission for your request, with the following method which will present Login window:
- (void)showLoginWindow:(id)sender {
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]showOAuthLoginControllerFromViewController:self withCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(success?@"L0L success":@"O noes!!! Loggen faylur!!!");
    }];
}
```

when the Login window is presented, enter your `Twitter` Username and Password to authenticate your request.

add the following methods to your code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loadAccessToken];
    NSString *username = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loggedInUsername];// self.engine.loggedInUsername;
    if (username.length > 0) {
        lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Logged in as %@",username];
        [self listResults];


    } else {
        lbl.text = @"You are not logged in.";
    }

}
- (void)storeAccessToken:(NSString *)accessToken {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:accessToken forKey:@"SavedAccessHTTPBody"];
}

- (NSString *)loadAccessToken {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"SavedAccessHTTPBody"];
}
4.Now you are ready to get your request, with the following method(in this method I created a `Twitter` search for some `Hashtag`, to get the screen_name for example):

- (void)listResults {

    dispatch_async(GCDBackgroundThread, ^{
        @autoreleasepool {
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

        // the following line contains a FHSTwitterEngine method wich do the search.

            dict = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]searchTweetsWithQuery:@"#iOS" count:100 resultType:FHSTwitterEngineResultTypeRecent unil:nil sinceID:nil maxID:nil];
          // NSLog(@"%@",dict);
            NSArray *results = [dict objectForKey:@"statuses"];

          //  NSLog(@"array text = %@",results);
            for (NSDictionary *item in results) {
                NSLog(@"text == %@",[item objectForKey:@"text"]);
                NSLog(@"name == %@",[[item objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"name"]);
                NSLog(@"screen name == %@",[[item objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"screen_name"]);
                NSLog(@"pic == %@",[[item objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"profile_image_url_https"]);
            }

            dispatch_sync(GCDMainThread, ^{
                @autoreleasepool {
                    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Complete!" message:@"Your list of followers has been fetched" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [av show];
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

That's all. I just got the `screen_name` from a `search Query`, you can get a timeline for a user using the following methods:

```
// statuses/user_timeline
- (id)getTimelineForUser:(NSString *)user isID:(BOOL)isID count:(int)count;
- (id)getTimelineForUser:(NSString *)user isID:(BOOL)isID count:(int)count sinceID:(NSString *)sinceID maxID:(NSString *)maxID;
```

instead of the search method above.

> Note: see the `FHSTwitterEngine.h` to know what method you need to use.
>   Note: to get the `<consumer_key>` and the `<consumer_secret>` you need to
>   to visit this link to `register` your app in `Twitter`.

Comment: Thanks!!!    I am also using the FHSTwitterEngine library but instead of calling fetchMethod in viewWillAppear ...I am trying to call it under showLogin Method success block..

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the following library.

https://github.com/nst/STTwitter

It is a lightweight Objective-C wrapper for Twitter REST API 1.1.

Look at the ReadMe and Demo project for examples

This is just one of the many methods the library has:

```
- (void)getUserTimelineWithScreenName:(NSString *)screenName
                         successBlock:(void(^)(NSArray *statuses))successBlock
                           errorBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))errorBlock;
```